# Getting subclassed UITableViewCell from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I was calling
`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

from
`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

in order to change the cell accessory. This works fine, but I ended up needing to subclass UITableViewCell.  What's the correct way to get the subclassed UITableViewCell?  Alternative A:
`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

returns an object that is
`CustomCell: 0x4527ed0; baseClass = UITableViewCell`

but won't respond to
`cell.customAccessoryImage;`

Alternative B won't compile
`CustomCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to cast it like this and access it as a CustomCell object

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

Justin's right. Are you needing to change the accessory view after the table's set up, though? Typically the best place to do that kind of setup is in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.